# How to improve nested loop in C#?

Tags: c#, loops

I have a function to calculate the costMatrix like this code below.

```
public double[,] makeCostMatrixClassic(List<PointD> firstSeq, List<PointD> secondSeq)
{
    double[,] costMatrix = new double[firstSeq.Count, secondSeq.Count];
    costMatrix[0, 0] = Math.Round(this.getEuclideanDistance(firstSeq[0], secondSeq[0]), 3);
    //  For D(n,1)
    for (int i = 0; i < firstSeq.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            costMatrix[i, 0] += Math.Round(this.getEuclideanDistance(firstSeq[j], secondSeq[0]), 3);
        }
    }
    //  For D(1,m)
    for (int i = 0; i < secondSeq.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            costMatrix[0, i] += Math.Round(this.getEuclideanDistance(firstSeq[0], secondSeq[j]), 3);
        }
    }
    //  For D(n,m)
    for (int i = 1; i < firstSeq.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < secondSeq.Count; j++)
        {
            double min = this.findMin(costMatrix[i - 1, j - 1], costMatrix[i - 1, j], costMatrix[i, j - 1]);
            costMatrix[i, j] = min + Math.Round(this.getEuclideanDistance(firstSeq[i], secondSeq[j]), 3);
        }
    }
    return costMatrix;
}
```

For the 3rd loop (n,m), how could i improve its performance if the "count" of each Sequence is 1 million points.

Comment: use `Parallel.For Loop` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: It seems to be off topic. this post is for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'd start off by following .NET naming conventions, to improve the *readability* of the code... and without knowing what `findMin` and `getEuclideanDistance` do, it's hard to know where the bottleneck is. Have you used a profiler at all? (You *might* want to use jagged arrays instead of rectangular arrays... they have different performance characteristics.)

Comment: Can you post getEuclideanDistance? and find min?

Comment: And you could use the basics of multi threading - the third loop could eas well be created as a set of tasks that then use your computer fully. May not make a difference on a small machine, but once you hit those super modern 36 core intel dual xeon workstations (with 72 threads available) that wil lbe a HUGH difference....

Comment: Just forget about `getEuclideanDistance()` and `findMin()`. They're just function which return Euclidean Distance and minimum of 3 numbers. What i wanna ask is the complexity of nested loop is O(n^2). So if each sequence has 1 millions as count like a said, it's really take a **LONG** time to execute.

Comment: Yeah, so either find a way to cut down on that, or welcome to the world of HPC where you ahve hundreds of computers solving a problem. This, though, loooks like something that can be optimized in algorithm - but that is beyond the scope of this site (because we ned to know the whole exact problem to come up with a better solution).

Comment: Threading will only do so much 2-4x faster at best

Comment: Shorten the name of `getEuclideanDistance` so that it fits onto our page without HScrollbar! - Other than that, what do you expect? You have a lot to do, so it is..